# How to form complex mysql query that has left outer join, aggregate data with group by using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How to write the following query using SQLAlchemy?

```
SELECT i.itemid, sum(i.quantitysold) total_quantity_sold, max(t.createdAt) last_sale_time
FROM ItemList i LEFT OUTER JOIN ItemTransactions t ON i.itemid = t.itemid
WHERE i.active = 'y'
GROUP BY i.itemid
ORDER BY total_quantity_sold asc;
```

This is what I ended up writing:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func as sa_func

query = ItemList.query.with_entities(ItemList.itemid)
query = query.outerjoin(ItemTransactions, ItemTransactions.itemid == ItemList.itemid)
query = query.add_columns(sa_func.sum(ItemList.quantitySold).label('total_quantity_sold'))
query = query.add_columns(sa_func.max(ItemTransactions.createdAt).label('last_sale_time'))
query = query.filter(ItemList.active == "y")
query = query.group_by(ItemList.itemid)
query = query.order_by(sa_func.sum(ItemList.quantitySold).asc())

if limit is not None and limit is not 0:
    query = query.limit(limit)
if offset is not None:
    query = query.offset(offset)

# Execute the query
sales = query.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

query = ItemList.query.with_entities(ItemList.itemid)
query = query.outerjoin(ItemTransactions, ItemTransactions.itemid == ItemList.itemid)
query = query.add_columns(func.sum(ItemList.quantitySold).label('total_quantity_sold'))
query = query.add_columns(func.max(ItemTransactions.createdAt).label('last_sale_time'))
query = query.filter(ItemList.active == "y")
query = query.group_by(ItemList.itemid)
query = query.order_by(func.sum(ItemList.quantitySold).asc())
```